# snowflake need to throw error when bulk copy same bucket

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to force an error when we insert the file from same bucket in same table..

Usually when we copy into a table and if the file is already copied then no data is loaded.
and if we need to load it again we use the command.

```
force=true
```

However our need is to throw the error when the staging area is not updated. And since the staging area is not under our control (its belong to other team) we cannot do any change there.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `copy_history` table and create one stored procedure use `throw` to raise error like below. Where is val is the filename you want to copy , if it already loaded it will throw error.

```
create or replace procedure ifcopied(val varchar)
                                   returns varchar
                                   language javascript
                                   execute as caller
                                   as
                                   $$
                                   var sql_command = `select count(status) from table(information_schema.copy_history(table_name=>'T1', start_time=> dateadd(hours, -1, current_timestamp()))) 
                                                        where file_name ='` + VAL + "'";
                                   var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:sql_command});                       
                                   var res = stmt.execute();
                                   res.next();
                                   row_status = res.getColumnValue(1);
                                   if (row_status == 1) {
                                   throw "File Already Loaded"
                                   } else {
                                   var sql_copy = `copy into T1 from @%T1/` + VAL ;
                                   var stmt_copy = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:sql_copy}).execute();
                                   }
                                   $$
                                   ;
call ifcopied('test5.gz');
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of FORCE = TRUE from the official Snowflake docs:

> Boolean that specifies to load all files, regardless of whether
> they’ve been loaded previously and have not changed since they were
> loaded. Note that this option reloads files, potentially duplicating
> data in a table.

If you have a requirement to use this option but ask if you can throw an error if the file is not updated, then no, the very definition of this option is to load the files again even if they have not changed.

I guess the question remains why you would use this option to load the data again when it hasn't changed (if that is what you are trying to avoid).  Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean by "staging area is not updated".

Comment: i know force=true. Will reload the table, and if i don't use the force then it wont load however my requirement is to deliberately throw error when stage is not updated.. so that  my teams get to know.. that nothing got updated today through scheduler.

Comment: Ah, ok, I  understand now. Thanks for clarifying for the forum audience. Looks like you got a good answer above.